# How to get the contents of a directory in a list in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, directory

I tried the below code but it shows error of static members cannot be accessed in initializers

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 // This widget is the root of your application.
var dir = new Directory('C:/Users/Admin/AndroidStudioProjects/idea/assets');
List contents = dir.listSync();
for (var fileOrDir in contents) {
if (fileOrDir is File) {
print(fileOrDir.name);
} else if (fileOrDir is Directory) {
print(fileOrDir.path);
}
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData()
```

Answer (score 3):

you have a syntax error. you need to add your snipped code in build method or in another method. your code should be something like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 // This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var dir = new Directory('C:/Users/Admin/AndroidStudioProjects/idea/assets');
  List contents = dir.listSync();
  for (var fileOrDir in contents) {
    if (fileOrDir is File) {
    print(fileOrDir.name);
    } else if (fileOrDir is Directory) {
    print(fileOrDir.path);
    }
  }
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData()
```

Comment: There is no more syntax error but it shows there is no such file or directory as the directory mention in the dir variable

Comment: Directory('C:/Users/Admin/AndroidStudioProjects/idea/assets') do not exist because when you run flutter this code will execute on your mobile device like android. and android does not have derive C and so on. you need to learn more about flutter and files. ;)

Comment: is there any other way get the contents of the assets folder when the code executes on the mobile device?